# What's the difference between Monitor RGB and sRGB?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, rgb, color-spaces

Since the output is web, RGB is choosen, but is there any difference between "Monitor RGB..." and "sRGB..."?

In Photoshop, they are both under `color settings > working spaces > RGB`

Answer (score 2):

They *can* be the same, or at least appear to be the same, depending upon your monitor calibration settings.

The Monitor RGB setting uses the calibration profile for your monitor. That **may be** sRGB or not. You could easily calibrate your monitor to be wildly different than sRGB.

The sRGB setting uses sRGB.

Comment: So what would you consider to be best practice for web output? I've seen 2 reviews of this in respectable sites, where one endorses 'Monitor RGB' an the other 'sRGB'.

Comment: I use sRGB for all web output. Nothing should ever be output to Monitor RGB. If you use Monitor RGB things will look right **to you** on **your monitor** but there's no telling what anyone else will see. Anyone touting the use of Monitor RGB doesn't really understand color management.

Comment: From this article http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/ the first paragraph feels like they're talking about web practices, in the end they might be talking about disabling color mangamentent for cross device consistency, or so. Then there is this other article http://www.newbreedmarketing.com/blog/color-management-best-practices-for-web-design proposing what you also say, so that was my confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah.. Marc (bjango) has posted here. He's prolific in posting, but he's completely wrong. I strongly disagree with him. And so do many, many other professionals. Look at http://digitaldog.net for **accurate** color info. Andrew Rodney is considered the master of color management in many professional circles. DigitalDog.net is far, far, more accurate than Bjango.

Answer (score 1):

sRGB is what most PC's and monitors use and it will display reasonably well on emails and web pages without the need for any color management software (web browsers and the like do not offer color management). While sRGB is generally well matched for your average PC monitor, the "container" is rather small with this color space: it doesn't cover some of the more vibrant and saturated shades that might possible to capture with the camera and reproduce on your printer. That brings us to Adobe RGB. Adobe RGB is a larger color space than sRGB, meaning that the container is large enough to hold colors that would be "clipped" in sRGB space due to those colors being too bright/saturated to be reproduced in the smaller sRGB container. Shooting/storing images in the Adobe RGB color space will allow you to capture and therefore later reproduce vibrant, saturated colors like deep yellows, cyans, and magenta colors found in subjects like flowers, some clothing dyes, and other subjects with very deep and saturated color.

for more details check here http://www.steves-digicams.com/knowledge-center/in-camera-color-spaces.html

Comment: Hi, both options that I presented are sRGB. Look at it yourself into photoshop. That's why I can't make a difference, I just did not write the full options names.

Answer (score 0):

sRGB is the web standard, you should/must be using this color space.

Monitor RGB can be what ever you monitor is calibrated to. There for if you have calibrated your monitor you should have it in the proof settings so you can proof all your colors as you work.

For example, sRGB on my computer lacks some red in Photoshop, so it may look fine till i proof it, then I realize its extra red every where else as well. So i proof and tame the red.